# how do I best represent a many-to-many relationship with additional info in a REST API?

Tags: api, rest

Lets say I have two resources, user and blog.
These are each represented by their own API endpoints in typical REST fashion as :

`api/users/`
`api/users/<id>/`

`api/blogs/`
`api/blogs/<id>/`

I also want to be able to represent a many-to-many relationship between the two, subscriptions. A user can subscribe to many blogs, and blogs can be subscribed to by many users. There is a unique constraint on this relationship on user ID and blog ID, so there can never be two entries with the same user ID and blog ID combo. The subscription also contains extra information such as subscription date, preferred email frequency, etc that the client may want to edit.

What is the best way to represent this relationship in conventional REST format?

I keep seeing two options as I have been searching on this topic:

1. use a nested resource like `api/users/<user_id>/blogs/<blog_id>/`, but to me, this implies that the response will be a blog object and not the subscription object which has additional subscription information that the client needs to be able to interact with.
2. create a discrete endpoint for the subscription object like `api/subscriptions/<id>/` where it is obvious that the object being interacted with is the subscription itself.

The dilemma I have with method 2 relates comes from deciding on a unique identifier for a specific subscription. Behind the scenes in my database, there is a unique auto-incremented integer ID for each subscription which I COULD use, but it would be more convenient for the client if they can access a specific subscription using both the user ID and blog ID especially since the combo is guaranteed to be unique. For example, if user 12 wants to subscribe to blog 34, that can potentially be done in one request `PUT api/subscriptions/<some-way-to-specify-user-ID-12-and-blog-ID-34>`, where the backend will check if this combo key exists and either update or create it. Otherwise, if using the actual subscription ID, the client has to first do a `GET api/subscriptions/?user_id=12&blog_id=34` so that it can discover the subscription ID to use if one exists THEN make a `POST api/subscriptions/` to create or `PUT api/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/` to update the entry. Or is this a weird thing that I am striving for in wanting to make a two-key identifier? Am I better off just using the natural subscription ID and making the client search for it?

Is there a standard/conventional/recommended way to represent this relationship? Are there other options that I haven't come across?

Answer (score 0):

You can use both, and it does not make much sense to think on the nice URI, because you will never hardcode different URIs into your REST client. Your client will get the URIs from the service and decide which one to follow based on the metadata attached to them. The concept is the same as browsing a web page. If you do something different, that is not REST. [https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/fielding_dissertation.pdf](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/fielding_dissertation.pdf) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS